# In Signs, Graham Hess had to comfort a dying woman in the past after a truck hit her and cut her in half

Tags: aliens, signs

How did he and this woman (named Coleen) know each other and Graham’s kids?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe Colleen was his wife. It's all made very clear in the [movie](https://youtube.com/watch?v=Fp6UIhiWeZY).

Comment: Exactly that. Her death is the reason why Graham loses faith and stops being a priest while his daughter gets the mild neurosis in form of placing glasses full of water everywhere.